# Wordpress url customization

Tags: permalinks

I want my url structure to looks like- mydomain.com/%articles%/%postname%-%post_ID.html anybody help me? In first image you can see how my permalink structure looks like, after domain name there is category name but i don't want the category name in my permalink, despite that i want to use word articles after domain name and after post name, as you can see in second image the site WSJ.com uses the word articles for the posts in permalink structure for each post.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think perhaps you're looking for `mydomain.com/articles/%postname%-%post_ID.html` right? You can set your permalinks for posts to `/articles/%postname%-%post_ID%` and that will put them at that "subfolder." From there it's a matter of figuring out how to enable the `.html` "extension" - you could use a plugin or research that part farther if you want to roll your own solution.

Comment: There is a problem when i set like this way, after applying this way if i click on pages like contact us then it "articles" shows in url,

Comment: If i did it this way then if i click on pages like contact us then it "articles" shows up in the url box despite that i want it to be shown for posts only, basicallg it can be done by rewrite rule but the problem is i don't know it.

Comment: Pretty permalinks give you settings for both Posts and Pages. Setting this way just for Posts should not affect your Pages. If it is, you may have a plugin adjusting things or may need to work with your host to see why Pretty Permalinks aren't working as intended.